How to use "qualified this" with name clash?
I've got two classes from dependencies, let's call them both Demo, in package com.example.a and package com.example.b.
I want to create two extension functions in the same file to convert between the two Demo classes.
I need to reference the outer this in a scoped function.
I tried the following two solutions, but neither compiles:
1.
import com.example.a.Demo as DemoA
import com.example.b.Demo as DemoB

fun DemoA.toDemoB(): DemoB =
    foo {
       name = this@DemoA.name
    }

fun DemoB.toDemoA(): DemoA =
    foo {
        name = this@DemoB.name
    }




fun com.example.a.Demo.toDemoB(): com.example.b.Demo =
    foo {
       name = this@com.example.a.Demo.name
    }

fun com.example.a.Demo.toDemoA(): com.example.a.Demo =
    foo {
        name = this@com.example.b.Demo.name
    }


What were the compile errors?  And was func a typo in the question, or was that in the code?

@gidds func was a typo in the question, I've updated the question accordingly. As @Leviathan shared the answer, this isn't relevant, but the error was:
    name = this@DemoA.name
                        ^


The qualified this doesn't specify the class name, it specifies the scope:
fun DemoA.toDemoB(): DemoB = foo {
    name = this@toDemoB.name
}

fun DemoB.toDemoA(): DemoA = foo {
    name = this@toDemoA.name
}

In the first function, this@toDemoB refers to the receiver of the function toDemoB (that is a DemoA object). You could also use this@foo to refer to the inner scope, the parameter's receiver of the function foo.
In the second function, this@toDemoA refers to the receiver of the function toDemoA (that is a DemoB object).
There are no conflicts here.

Here's the best answer I could come up with. It's not ideal as it's less concise than option 1, but at least it compiles.
import com.example.a.Demo as DemoA
import com.example.b.Demo as DemoB

fun DemoA.toDemoB(): DemoB {
    val demoA = this
    return foo {
       name = demoA.name
    }
}

fun DemoB.toDemoA(): DemoA {
    val demoB = this
    return foo {
        name = demoB.name
    }
}

